# Read local JSON with Javascript [Discord bot]

Tags: javascript, json, bots, discord

I want to extract the data of my .json file and show it in the discord channel filtering by the name given.
In this case the `msg` variable contains the name i want to search for.

```
var msg;
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + prefix)) {
    msg = message.content;
    message.channel.send(msg.substring(2)); //this is just for testing
}
```

Now having the name I don't know how to search in my .json file and extract the data.
This is part of my .json file

```
{
  "ID": "1",
  "Nombre": "luffy caca",
  "Tipo": "str",
  "Clase principal": "fighter"
},
{
  "ID": "2",
  "Nombre": "luffy manco",
  "Tipo": "int",
  "Clase principal": "slasher"
},
{
  "ID": "3",
  "Nombre": "luffy g2",
  "Tipo": "str",
  "Clase principal": "driven",
  "Clase secundaria": "slasher"
}
```

So I want to extract the data of 'ID:3' when I got the name "luffy g2" on my `msg` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var msg =[
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "Nombre": "luffy caca",
      "Tipo": "str",
      "Clase principal": "fighter"
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "Nombre": "luffy manco",
      "Tipo": "int",
      "Clase principal": "slasher"
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "Nombre": "luffy g2",
      "Tipo": "str",
      "Clase principal": "driven",
      "Clase secundaria": "slasher"
    }
  ];
  
  var idToFind = msg.find(x => x.Nombre == "luffy g2").ID;
  
  console.log(idToFind);
```

The [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method will:

> the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the
>   provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea but im trying to read from the .json file not from the variable.

Comment: What does message.content look like?